# Remove the double quotes in JSON String created using GSON

Tags: java, apache-spark

I got the below result in spark after using GSON library.

```
[
  "{"A":"1","A-Description":"Eastern                                           "}",
  "{"B":"2","B-Description":"Western                                           "}",
  "{"C":"3","C-Description":"Northern                                          "}",
  "{"D":"4","D-Description":"Southern"}"
]
```

I want to remove the double quotes from start and end of json string

Final result will be as below :

```
[
  {"A":"1","A-Description":"Eastern                                           "},
  {"B":"2","B-Description":"Western                                           "},
  {"C":"3","C-Description":"Northern                                          "},
  {"D":"4","D-Description":"Southern"}
]
```

I have solved the issue as below :

```
val jsonString = str.replaceAll("\\\\", "").replaceAll("\"(.+)\"", "$1")
```

where str is some string.

Please suggest more efficient way if available.

Comment: I'd check why those double quotes are there in the first place and try to remove those. Removing them after the fact feels wrong and seems fragile.

Comment: Can you show us to how you got your json and how serialize it?

Comment: Please, can you paste your snippet to see what's causing this?

Comment: Seems you converted a list of strings to JSON. Instead, put the objects into the list without first converting them to JSON individually.

Comment: I have used the Gson Library with Spark to get JSON. Basic requirement is to convert csv data to json data and I do not want to use the dataframe's class toJSON method. I have used  new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create() for JSON conversion.

Comment: If you remove the quotes, you literally have columns **2x the number of rows** in your data: `column 1: "A", column 2: "A-Description", column 3: "B", column 4: "B-Description".... and so on`. Are you sure you want to do that?